# Kotlin Android Spinner crashes app on load

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

Hello i have been modifying an App and i have been following the examples given by Android to create a Spinner but my App crashes once it loads, the exact part that crashes it is **spinner.adapter = adapter**. The app uses a fragmented view and i have tried placing the following code into the onCreate and onViewCreated but both crash the app? What am i doing wrong, I have read the 4 matching posts to mine but they use Java and had issues getting null values but my code is to load a static array already created in the strings.xml.

below i have listed all the code i have implemented for this Spinner box have i missed something?

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val spinner = R.id.modeSpinner as Spinner
    val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(activity, R.array.rgb_mode_options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.adapter = arrayAdapter
}
```

and in my strings.xml

```
<string-array name="rgb_mode_options">
    <item>Steady On</item>
    <item>Pulse</item>
    <item>Chase</item>
    <item>Rainbow</item>
    <item>Comet</item>
    <item>Candle</item>
    <item>Warm White</item>
    <item>Cool White</item>
</string-array>
```

and main.xml

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/modeSpinner"
    android:layout_width="182dp"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="312dp"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

and finally the SpinnerActivity which is in its own tab named SpinnerActivity.kt

```
package com.thanksmister.iot.esp8266.vo

import android.app.Activity
import android.view.View
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.Toast

class SpinnerActivity : Activity(), AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, pos: Int, id: Long) {
        // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
        // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, pos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
        // Another interface callback
    }
}
```

[Spinner tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner)

EDIT:
I have tried

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(getLayoutId())
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.modeSpinner)
val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, 
R.array.rgb_mode_options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.adapter = arrayAdapter
```

But i looking at the logcat i see

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: spinner must not be null

Comment: post the error from logcat

Comment: I get the error, Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: spinner must not be null

Comment: the last onCreate method is related to which activity? are you overriding it in SpinnerActivity?

Answer (score 1):

`R.id.modeSpinner` is an integer ID, you can't cast it to `Spinner`.

Use `val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.modeSpinner)`

Remember to set your layout *before* accessing views.

```
setContentView(R.layout.main)
```

Comment: I get the error, Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: spinner must not be null

Comment: I can't use findViewById in onViewCreated, onCreateView in my fragmented view so i tried it in my onCreate but i get the same error being null spinner?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the fix was to remove **val spinner = R.id.modeSpinner as Spinner**
including **val spinner = findViewById(R.id.modeSpinner)**, instead just referred directly as modeSpinner.

so the code is now

```
val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(activity, R.array.rgb_mode_options, 
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)

arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
modeSpinner.adapter = arrayAdapter
```

Answer (score -1):

**Spinner in Android with Kotlin**

I've migrated to Android X.

```
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                android:id="@+id/spn_test"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I have written two extension functions takes an `int` for initial selection, and 
`Enumeration` or `ArrayList` respectively and returns a `String` which is the name of the selected item.

**Extension for Enumeration:**

```
fun <T> AppCompatSpinner.spinnerAdapterEnumeration(position: Int, array: Array<T>): String {
    var selectedItem: String = ""
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array)
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    this.adapter = adapter
    this.setSelection(position)
    this.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
        }

        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
            selectedItem = (array[position] as Enum<*>).name
        }
    }
    return selectedItem
}
```

**Extension for ArrayList:**

```
fun AppCompatSpinner.spinnerAdapterArray(position: Int, array: ArrayList<String>): String {
    var selectedItem: String = ""
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array)
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    this.adapter = adapter
    this.setSelection(position)
    this.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
        }

        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
            selectedItem = array[position]
        }
    }
    return selectedItem

}
```

**Usage:**

```
enum class Test(type: String) {
    Existing("EXISTING"),
    New("NEW")
}
```

In your `View` of your *architecture*.

```
val selectedItem: String = spn_test.spinnerAdapter(1, Test.values())
```

**NOTE:** Also, If you are using any views(TextView, Spinner etc.. in your `Fragment` by using Kotlin synthetic, As the context of the Fragment, could be `null` for security you can use it like this

```
spn_test?.spinnerAdapter(1, Test.values())
txt_test?.text = "Kotlin is awesome!"
```